# pdf file resists converting to ps and printing

Tags: pdf, printing, ps

I'd like to print this file:

http://florian-konnertz.de/public/Psychology_of_Computer_Programming.pdf

I cant find out how I do that here. I tried on our Kyocera FD 2000 beside from pdf viewers from command line via

```
lpr -P printername filename.pdf
```

Printer tells me KPDL error, which I just acknowledge but print order is cancelled.

The other huge laser printers in the office just dismisses the job.

Also pdf2ps hangs.

So it seems to be a quite hard to interpret pdf type.

Any tips appreciated what I can try further.

Comment: @ groovhunter: Which operating system are you using? (In case you are on an older Unix, or on Windows, you cannot expect the print subsystem to auto-convert your PDF to PostScript. If you throw the unfiltered PDF to the printer port, it may well behave like you describe.) -- Also, your topic part *"converting to PS"* isn't elaborated at all in your text. How did you try to convert to PS exactly? What message of resistance did you encounter?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not help you much, but I was able to print the first dozen pages just fine. I used Adobe Reader, and printed to Distiller.

You might try one of the suggestions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/278562/repair-corrupt-pdf) to use ghostscript to repair the PDF.