# Font contains bad /Widths - PDF error

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat

I have PDF file which designed very long before and its contains some fonts which are unavailable in my new computer. The PDF file shows the blank white space in adobe reader, but if I open it in my browser its showing all the text properly. Also I have Acrobat Pro and i tried to copy the text with Acrobat Pro text tool, But its copying confused characters such as symbols. How to repair my PDF?

The Adobe reader says the below error

> The font 'Font-name' contains bad /Widths

I want to send this file to a person, So that my PDF file must be standardized with all readers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix/repair a corrupted PDF file?](http://superuser.com/questions/278562/how-can-i-fix-repair-a-corrupted-pdf-file)

Comment: I've gone through the your result. That is not my exact problem. Also I cant understand that procedures.

Answer (score 1):

That means it is font problem. Try [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/), it will auto detect and download corresponding font that you needed.

Comment: My browser runs in adobe reader plugin.

Comment: If you prefer to view pdf in browser, Foxit Reader is also support so.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant say that seems it not the PDF reader problem. It might be the file problem. And I want to send it to one other person, so that I can't endorse him the specific reader.

Comment: Didn't notice you are going to send this file to someone. Anyway once you are able to read the PDF on your computer correctly, you can recreate the PDF with some software like [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/). This should fix the problem.

Comment: If I can recreate the PDF file from Browser then, It will be fine. By the way I tried the two things with my browser, 1. I downloaded the file , 2. I printed to file. Both are failed

Comment: Hi, I have added the error message also. Kindly help me.

Comment: First thing to check, are you able to open the PDF and display it correctly with whatever software on your computer at this time?

Comment: I can view everything(pictures, colors, designs) except the text. the text area shows blank. But, I can see the text too only in browser, as I already said.

Comment: It would be cool if you could share the specify file with us. Is it a public file that you could share?