# How to use GhostScript for Windows to repair damaged PDF files

Tags: windows-7, pdf

My PDF file is corrupted, then after searching the web I found a good thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/278562/how-can-i-fix-repair-a-corrupted-pdf-file).
Since I hadn't *gswin32c* on my Windows 7 x86 system I installed it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/). Now I have it on my system and ran it now! :)
But my problem is that how to use the commands written there as follows:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o repaired.pdf ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
   corrupted.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I use the following commands:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o repaired.pdf ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
   corrupted.pdf
```

Note that the above is a **single** command. The `^` character is an [escape character](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), allowing the command to be split across multiple lines (it is escaping the `<eol>` characters).

So it could be written as:

```
gswin32c.exe -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress corrupted.pdf
```

To run this command:

1. Open a `cmd` shell
2. Change directory to the location of the PDF file:

   ```
    cd c:\PathToMypdf
   ```
3. Run the following command:

   ```
    c:\PathToGswin\gswin32c.exe -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress corrupted.pdf
   ```

Notes:

- If `PathToMypdf` contains spaces then the directory needs to be quoted:

  ```
   cd "c:\PathToMypdf"
  ```
- if `PathToGswin` contains spaces then the command needs to be quoted:

  ```
   "c:\PathToGswin\gswin32c.exe" -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress corrupted.pdf
  ```

---

#### C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

> My pdf file with the name p2.pdf is in this diretory: `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Attach`.
>
> And the `gswin32c.exe` is in this directory: `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\bin`
>
> When I run this command:
>
> `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32c.exe -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress p2.pdf`
>
> I get the following error "C:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> What part is wrong please?

You need to run the following commands:

```
cd C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Attach
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32c.exe" -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress p2.pdf
```

Notes:

- The `"`s are required because the path `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\bin\` contains spaces.

Comment: My pdf file with the name _p2.pdf_ is in this path: _C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Attach_. And the _gswin32c.exe_ is in this path: _C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\bin_ When I run this command: _C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Attach>C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32c.exe -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress p2.pdf_, the cmd says:_'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file._!! What part is wrong please?

Comment: @franky Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. I made your reply an answer. But although it worked (with the message _GPL Ghostscript 9.09: unrecoverable error, exit code 1_), it couldn't recover my pdf properly. It yielded a bland _repaird_ pdf file. :(

Comment: @franky It looks like your PDF can't be recovered using `gswin`. You need to look for other recovery methods.