# How to repair or recover my Word and PDF files

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, pdf, data-recovery

My Windows 7 was infected and the malware destroyed both of my Word and PDF files.
I searched the web much but couldn't find a way to really help me on recovering or repairing those two files. I found one good thread on this website and used *gswin32c.exe* ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/1066419/how-to-use-ghostscript-for-windows-to-repair-damaged-pdf-files) but no success).
Is there any real way to use for recovering/repairing those two files?

PS: I don't have any back-up of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguos but I will try to help you.

If you have been infected by a ransomware you are in trouble. This malware cyphers all your data and asks you to pay if you want to recover it. If it's the case the only factible way to recover your information is through a security copy or with the [previous version of files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7). You can also recover the files if they were plaved in a cloud synchronized foolder (Dropbox, Mega, Drive, ...)

I highly recoomend you to do copies of your files periodically, on the cloud or in a backup disk and have a good antivirus updated in yor PC.

If this is not the case please, explain your problem with more detail.

Angel Sanchis