# How can I fix a pdf that can only be opened with mupdf?

Tags: pdf, repair, pdf-reader, ghostscript

I have a pdf file which can only be opened with mupdf (both desktop and mobile) I've tried opening the same file with evince, okular, foxit reader and with my kindle paperwhite 2018. I ultimately tried the methods described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/278562/how-can-i-fix-repair-a-corrupted-pdf-file) (ghostscript, pdftocairo, mutool clean) still no results.

Comment: What happens why you try the other programs? What errors do you get? Where is the PDF from? Can you get another copy and see if your version is corrupted? What do you mean "no results"?

Comment: With evince
Unable to open document "path_of_the_document"
PDF document is damaged

Comment: With ghostscript: 
 `gs  -o repaired.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress corrupted.pdf`

You can find the output on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8Knq9ihV)

Comment: with pdftocairo:
`pdftocairo -pdf print.pdf print_repaired.pdf`
 The ouput is the following :
`Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Error opening PDF file.`

Comment: with `mutool clean input.pdf output.pdf` the output is the following : `error: cannot recognize version marker
warning: trying to repair broken xref
warning: repairing PDF document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found a way to manage this.

- You'll need `mutool` ([project page](https://mupdf.com/))
- On fedora it's available in the package `mupdf`you can install it with the command: 
  `sudo dnf install -y mupdf`

If you read the manpage, you may think that you need `mupdf clean`. However, if it doesn't work, what you'll need is `mutool convert` ([documentation](https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-convert.html))

```
mutool convert [options] -o output input [pages]

 The 'mutool convert' command converts an input file into another format.
```

In this specific case:

`mutool convert -o output.pdf input.pdf`