# PDF Fixer: How to save restored content?

Tags: pdf

I downloaded a PDF file, but unfortunately the download was interrupted when I already got 43 of 44 MiB. I didn't want to download it again, and the browser was not smart enough to resume the download.

I tried to recover the data inside the almost complete file using the advice from this question: [How can I fix/repair a corrupted PDF file?](https://superuser.com/questions/278562/how-can-i-fix-repair-a-corrupted-pdf-file). But no success. Then I downloaded a Windows tool called PDF Fixer and installed it on my Ubuntu system with Wine.

After an eternity this tool came up with a preview window that showed some file content. The tool created a folder called FixedPDFs. It contained the repaired broken file and a small file with "_xref_fixed" in the name. The first still couldn't be opened, the second when opened had only a blank page.

Now how can I get a valid pdf from the content in the 2 files?

Comment: You cannot recover 7 MB worth of data that was never there. You might be able to see the pages that were downloaded but there isn’t a tool that exists that could recover the data that wasn’t downloaded

Comment: I did not ask for a magic tool that comes up with data that was never there. I'd like to know whether there is a way to assemble the output files from PDF Fixer in a way that will result in a readable PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the freeware PDF Fixer or Corrupt PDF Viewer can help you. They can restore you data from interupt PDF files:

https://pdffixer.com

https://pdffixer.com/corrupt-pdf-viewer.html

Comment: And my question is about a problem with PDF fixer.